# Sorting, filtering and paging within a modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to follow this tutorial [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), but trying to execute it within a modal. I am basically calling the index view inside my modal (not sure if that's best practice or not) However, every time I click on a header to sort or anything else the modal disappears and the page is redirected to the index view. Is this possible with the way I'm going about this and if not, maybe someone can suggest an alternative solution, I am kinda new to all of this!

Here is the partial that includes a button that calls the modal.

```
@model IEnumerable<ReconciliationApp.Models.IReconciliationForm>

<div class="img-responsive center-block" id="formButtons">
    <div>
        <div class="btn-group row col-sm-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".browse-modal-lg">Browse</button>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group row col-sm-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Modify</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">New</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade browse-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Browse Members</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left: 50px;">
                @Html.EditorForModel("Index")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my index view

```
@model IEnumerable<ReconciliationApp.Models.CSReconForm>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Modal";
}

<h2>CSRecon Browse</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Member ID", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Brand ID", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.MemberSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("First Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.BrandSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.FirstNameSortParm })
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Processed By", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LastNameSortParm })
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MemberID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BrandID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProcessedBy)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

And the part of my controller that is being used

```
    public class CSReconFormsController : ApplicationBaseController
    {
        private ReconciliationContext db = new ReconciliationContext();
        private ApplicationDbContext adb = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: CSReconForms
        public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
        {

            var usersContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var users = usersContext.Users.Select(u => u.UserName).ToList();
            ViewBag.Users = users;
            ViewBag.Title = "Modal";

            ViewBag.DateSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "dateCreated_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.MemberSortParm = sortOrder == "MemberId" ? "memberId_desc" : "MemberId";
            ViewBag.BrandSortParm = sortOrder == "BrandId" ? "brandId_desc" : "BrandId";
            ViewBag.FirstNameSortParm = sortOrder == "FirstName" ? "firstName_desc" : "FirstName";
            ViewBag.LastNameSortParm = sortOrder == "LastName" ? "lastName_desc" : "LastName";

            var reconForms = from s in db.CSReconForms select s;
            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "MemberId":
                    reconForms = reconForms.OrderBy(s => s.MemberID);
                    break;
                case "memberId_desc":
                    reconForms = reconForms.OrderByDescending(s => s.MemberID);
                    break;
                case "BrandId":
                    reconForms = reconForms.OrderBy(s => s.BrandID);
                    break;
                case "brandId_desc":
                    reconForms = reconForms.OrderByDescending(s => s.BrandID);
                    break;
                case "FirstName":
                    reconForms = reconForms.OrderBy(s => s.FirstName);
                    break;
                case "firstName_desc":
                    reconForms = reconForms.OrderByDescending(s => s.FirstName);
                    break;
                case "LastName":
                    reconForms = reconForms.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
                    break;
                case "lastName_desc":
                    reconForms = reconForms.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
                    break;
                case "dateCreated_desc":
                    reconForms = reconForms.OrderByDescending(s => s.WhenCreated);
                    break;
                default:
                    reconForms = reconForms.OrderBy(s => s.WhenCreated);
                    break;
            }
            return View(reconForms.ToList());
        }
       ...
     }
```

If there is anything else that you think you might might be useful, feel free to ask! Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to use a modal and stay on the same page, then use ajax to post the `sortOrder` value to a method that returns a partial view and update the DOM in its success callback (not links that do a redirect)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your headers are actually action links that redirect to the `Index()` method, which in turn returns the `Index` view.

> @Html.ActionLink("Member ID", "Index", new { sortOrder =
>   ViewBag.DateSortParm })

Instead of having the `Index` view inside a modal in the partial view, you should do it the other way around. And then when you create the header links, do not link them to server side action methods if you just want client side sorting. Instead implement client side sorting using JavaScript. You don't want a server trip just to sort some elements already present on the client side!

Answer (score 0):

Yes after after @AmateurProgrammer's (thanks!) comment I went and decided to try some javascript, which I had never done before. So after some research I ended up using the datatables JQuery plugin to work with. I found this tutorial [here](https://datatellblog.wordpress.com/2015/08/01/server-side-paging-with-datatables-net-and-mvc/), and modified it accordingly. I am posting my code for anyone who might be in a similar situation.

Here is the controller method where I get the data

```
        public JsonResult DataTableGet([ModelBinder(typeof(DataTablesBinder))] IDataTablesRequest requestModel)
        {

            IQueryable<CSReconForm> query = db.CSReconForms;

            var totalCount = query.Count();

            // Apply filters
            if (requestModel.Search.Value != String.Empty)
            {
                var value = requestModel.Search.Value.Trim();
                query = query.Where(p => p.MemberID.Contains(value) || p.BrandID.Contains(value));
            }

            var filteredCount = query.Count();

            // Sort
            var sortedColumns = requestModel.Columns.GetSortedColumns();
            var orderByString = String.Empty;

            foreach (var column in sortedColumns)
            {
                orderByString += orderByString != String.Empty ? "," : "";
                orderByString += (column.Data == "MemberID" ? "MemberID" : column.Data) + (column.SortDirection == Column.OrderDirection.Ascendant ? " asc" : " desc");
            }

            query = query.OrderBy(orderByString == String.Empty ? "MemberID asc" : orderByString);

            // Paging
            query = query.Skip(requestModel.Start).Take(requestModel.Length);

            var data = query.Select(p => new
            {
                Id = p.Id,
                MemberID = p.MemberID,
                BrandID = p.BrandID,
                FirstName = p.FirstName,
                LastName = p.LastName,
                WhenCreated = p.WhenCreated,
                ProcessedBy = p.ProcessedBy
            }).ToList();
            return Json(new DataTablesResponse(requestModel.Draw, data, filteredCount, totalCount), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Here is where I build the table within the HTML (yes I added this script, which built the table itself - no need for markup for the table itself)

```
             <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function () {

                        var controller = "@ViewData["controller"]";
                        var productListVM = {
                            dt: null,

                            init: function (oObj) {
                                dt = $('#data-table').DataTable({
                                    "serverSide": true,
                                    "processing": true,
                                    "ajax": "/" + controller + "/DataTableGet",
                                    "columns": [
                                        { "title": "MemberID", "data": "MemberID", "searchable": false },
                                        { "title": "BrandID", "data": "BrandID" },
                                        { "title": "FirstName", "data": "FirstName" },
                                        { "title": "LastName", "data": "LastName" },
                                        { "title": "WhenCreated", "data": "WhenCreated" },
                                        { "title": "ProcessedBy", "data": "ProcessedBy" },

                                        {
                                            data: null,
                                            className: "center",
                                            //re: `<a href="/${controller}/Edit/${}" class="editor_edit">Edit</a> / <a href="/${controller}/Delete/" class="editor_remove">Delete</a>`,
                                            "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {


                                                return '<a href="/' + controller + '/Edit/' + data.Id + '" class="editor_edit">Edit</a> / <a href="/' + controller + '/Delete/' + data.Id + '">Delete</a>';
                                            }
                                        },
                                    ],

                                    "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50], [5, 10, 25, 50]],
                                });
                            },

                            refresh: function () {
                                dt.ajax.reload();
                            }
                        }
                        // Edit record
                        $('#example').on('click', 'a.editor_edit', function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();

                            editor
                                .title('Edit record')
                                .buttons({ "label": "Update", "fn": function () { editor.submit() } })
                                .edit($(this).closest('tr'));
                        });

                        // Delete a record
                        $('#example').on('click', 'a.editor_remove', function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();

                            editor
                                .title('Edit record')
                                .message("Are you sure you wish to delete this row?")
                                .buttons({ "label": "Delete", "fn": function () { editor.submit() } })
                                .remove($(this).closest('tr'));
                        });

                        $('#refresh-button').on("click", productListVM.refresh);

                        productListVM.init();
                    })
                </script>
```